# Store<AppState> undefined within angular spec file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, ngrx, ngrx-store

**Issue**: store is undefined within angular spec file no matter whether the initial state is provided or not.

As a whole, I am not entirely sure what could be causing this issue. Followed the NGRX testing documentation to implement mock store. store variable should at least be defined to show an empty object if anything when console logging.

---

### .spec.ts

```
describe('HttpClient testing', () => {
  let myService: MyService;
  let store: Store<AppState>;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let initialState = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  });

  /// Tests begin ///

  it('#getValue should return real value from the real service', () => {
    console.log('store in testing', store) // => is undefined

    myService = new MyService(
      httpClient,
      new ExampleService(
        httpClient,
        store
      ),
    );
    expect(myService.getAll()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // After every test, assert that there are no more pending requests.
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });
});
```

### .service.ts

```
...@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ExampleService {
  public email: string = "";
  public name: string = "";
  public id: string = "";
  public cId: string = "";

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {
      this.cId = "1234";
      this.name = "test";
      this.email = "test@user.com";
      store.dispatch(
        SAVE_USER_INFO({
          email: this.email,
          name: this.name,
          id: this.id,
          cId: this.cId,
        })
      );
  }...
```

### AppState

```
...export interface AppState {
  myData: myDataRedux;
}

export const EXAMPLE_REDUCERS: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  myData: myDataReducer,
};...
```

Comment: i am not sure but can u try to inject the store like `store = TestBed.inject(Store);`

Comment: @ChrisY Just tried that. Did not seem to work

Comment: ok next try :)
I saw you are calling `compileComponents` - This is an async call so I think you should put it in a `beforeEach(async () => {...})`

As an alternative,  I think you can just go without calling `compileComponents`

see: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#compilecomponents-is-async

Comment: @ChrisY i just removed ```compileComponents```, still didnt not work. Store is undefined